# How to place JPanel at specified coordinates within another JPanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I am trying to create a clickable map that will draw villages based on their coordinates. However, they have to be selected by mouse click. The villages are connected via roads and Gnomes are traveling across them as individual threads. Therefore I currently have two problems, of which only the first one fit the title:

1. How do I create JPanels for each village and then place them at a specific coordinate within another JPanel
2. How do I constantly repaint the villages, gnomes, and roads while simultaneously listening for mouse clicks and allowing for various creation modes?

Some extra info:

A click on the map in village creation mode creates a new village

A click on a village will allow the option to delete it

Clicks on two villages will connect them with a road.

Comment: have u tried with setLocation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [GraphPanel](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) example by @trashgod which allows you to create nodes of different shapes.

You can then use "shift click" to select multiple nodes and then use the context menu (right clicking) to connect the nodes and draw a line between the two. You can also use the context menu to delete any node.

I have no idea how to have the gnomes travel along the roads, but it should be a start for you.